# Syntax error at or near closing parenthesis of FROM argument in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, syntax

Why is my PostgreSQL parser returning

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ... FROM continent LEFT JOIN (country INNER JOIN city) sw ON sw...
```

on the following SQL query, which attempts to list all continents and their number of countries whose capital's population is larger than 3 million:

```
SELECT continent.Name, COUNT(country.Name)
FROM continent LEFT JOIN (country INNER JOIN city) sw
ON sw.country.Area = continent.Area AND sw.country.Capital = sw.city.Name
AND sw.city.Country = sw.country.Name AND sw.city.Population > 3000000
GROUP BY continent.Name;
```

Comment: I don't see a join condition for that `INNER JOIN` -- I suspect that's what postgres is complaining about.

Comment: You're right. Correct.

Comment: `(country INNER JOIN city)`  doesn't make sense. What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: I thought you could do multiple joins and then put all ON conditions directly after one another after the final join.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL joining three tables, join precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780199/sql-joining-three-tables-join-precedence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, it looks like you're getting your join conditions mixed together. Something like this might work:

```
SELECT continent.Name, COUNT(country.Name)
FROM continent
  LEFT JOIN
    (country INNER JOIN city
     ON sw.country.Capital = sw.city.Name
     AND sw.city.Country = sw.country.Name) sw
  ON sw.country.Area = continent.Area
WHERE sw.city.Population > 3000000
GROUP BY continent.Name;
```

**Edit**

That didn't work -- the `sw` table group is referenced before it's declared. Let's try again:

```
SELECT continent.Name, COUNT(country.Name)
FROM continent
  LEFT JOIN country
    ON country.area = continent.area
  INNER JOIN city
    ON country.Capital = city.Name
   AND city.Country = country.Name
WHERE city.Population > 3000000
GROUP BY continent.Name;
```

I'm not certain that this join logic is exactly what you want, but the query parses without issue.

**Edit 2**

And one final version. This is (as far as I can tell) going to return the same results as the second query -- at the very least, it generates the same plan -- but more closely mirrors your initial query:

```
SELECT continent.Name, COUNT(sw.Country)
FROM continent
  LEFT JOIN
    (country INNER JOIN city
     ON country.Capital = city.Name
     AND city.Country = country.Name) sw
  ON sw.Area = continent.Area
WHERE sw.Population > 3000000
GROUP BY continent.Name;
```

Comment: The parser seems to react on the fact that the join within parentheses has no ON conditions.