# Laravel joining three tables, join precedence

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, query-optimization, laravel-5.3

I am trying to join three tables in my application. Below you can check the example table structure

```
Table A
----------------
| a_id |  b_fk |
----------------
| 1    |  2    |
----------------
| 2    |  2    |
----------------

Table b
----------------
| b_id |  c_fk |
----------------
| 1    |  1    |
----------------
| 2    |  1    |
----------------

Table C
----------------
| c_id |  value|
----------------
| 1    | aaa   |
----------------
| 2    | ccc   |
----------------
```

I want to join these three table and implement [join with precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780199/sql-joining-three-tables-join-precedence) using Laravel query builder

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN (b JOIN c ON (b.c_kf = c.id)) ON (a.b_fk = b.id);
```

I've tried to do something like this

```
DB::table('a')->leftJoin('b', function ($join){
    $join->leftjoin('c', 'b.c_fk', '=', 'c.id')
    ->on('a.b_fk', '=', 'b.id');
})
```

Which forms following query

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.b_fk = b.id);
```

Is there a way to join multiple tables in Laravel and implement precedence?

Comment: as you mentioned tag `laravel` so in laravel you can use relationship in eloquent

Comment: It's an old query which I am reworking on, for quick optimization to improve performance of application on our client system till next version of application rolls out.

Comment: so you can use relation for that or you have to go old fashion way.

Comment: We are already implementing the relationship between models to implement the same functionality, but as it would take more than a week to test/roll out new version and update system. Just for quick fix I'd like to use old fashion way to fix the issue.

Comment: I'm interested to see a performance comparison between the two approaches, if you have the interest to share your results once you've accomplished the quick fix of course.

Comment: @taavs we have implemented Laravel relationship as mentioned and results are pretty convincing to prefer relationship over joins. I am giving the links of screenshots to show you the results of both methods. We tried to get 100 records from a tables which contains 2 lack records and is related to a table which has over 4 lack records. You can see the ajax call took over a minute in joins while relationship took only 4 seconds. Results of join can be seen here https://pasteboard.co/H7J5Hgm.png. Results of eager loading can be seen here https://pasteboard.co/H7J5TD7.png

Comment: Not to forget this ajax response time includes time taken to execute query and process data before returning json response.

Comment: Thank you. That definitely helps me a lot.