# SQL : ISNULL in Join condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any other way to write this. If the Credit cardID in Application table is NULL, then join CreditcardID from Terminatedcreditcard table. Thanks,

This is the error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   The multi-part identifier "TC.CreditCardID" could not be bound.

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    prg.Title AS Program, a.Patientid,
    a. Applicationid,
    PT.MCC,
    PT.MerchantName,
    PT.MerchantCity, PT.MerchantState,
    PT.MerchantZip,
    PT.SettlementTransactionID,
    CONVERT(DATE, PT.SettlementDate) AS SettlementDate
    ABS(PT.Amount) as TransactionAmount
FROM 
    [dbo].[StagingSettlements] PT  
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Application a ON PT.[CustomId] = ISNULL(a.CreditCardId, TC.CreditCardID)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.TerminatedCreditCard TC ON TC.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change join [precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780199/sql-joining-three-tables-join-precedence) to get this:

```
FROM [dbo].[StagingSettlements] AS PT  
LEFT JOIN ( dbo.Application AS a
    LEFT JOIN dbo.TerminatedCreditCard AS TC on TC.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId )
        ON PT.[CustomId] = ISNULL( a.CreditCardId, TC.CreditCardID )
```

The addition of parentheses above causes `Application` to `TerminatedCreditCard` join to be evaluated first and the result is then joined to `StagingSettlements`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

1. You don't appear to actually be using a credit card number in your result set, so I'm not clear on why  you want it?
2. You need to put the NULL check in the join on TerminatedCreditCard.  You are getting the error because you are trying to reference TerminatedCreditCard before you have joined to it.

The below SQL should sort you out, I wasn't sure of what the join condition would be between StagingSettlements and application, so I have just put in a placeholder which you will need to update, I have also added a 'CreditCardId' to the select:

```
SELECT Distinct 
         prg.Title as Program
        ,a.Patientid
        ,a.Applicationid
        ,PT.MCC
        ,PT.MerchantName
        ,PT.MerchantCity
        ,PT.MerchantState
        ,PT.MerchantZip
        ,PT.SettlementTransactionID
        ,convert(Date,PT.SettlementDate) as SettlementDate
        ,ABS(PT.Amount) as TransactionAmount
        ,COALESCE(TC.CreditCardId, a.CreditCardId) as CreditCardId
FROM    [dbo].[StagingSettlements] PT  
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Application a
                ON      a.<applicationid> = PT.<applicationid>
            LEFT JOIN dbo.TerminatedCreditCard TC      
                ON      TC.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId 
                    AND a.CreditCardId IS NULL
```

Comment: It's not about using Creditcard ID in the result set. Sometimes the Creditcard ID in Application table is NULL so I wanted to join with the Creditcard ID in Terminated credit card table. 
And in your join condition, the StagingSettlements table doesn't have the ApplicationID field.

Comment: Yep - I see what you mean, given that I think you will find that Alex's answer will give you what you want.